# Insert HTML only after a full word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery to insert content after an anchor. For example, if I have the following:

```
<p>this is an example sentence with a link coming up (Here's the <a href='#' class='insertpoint'>link content</a>). More text may or may not follow here.</p>
```

Using the following:

```
$("a.insertpoint").click(function() {  
   var mapDiv = $("<div class='map' id='testmap'><img src='graphics/loading.gif'></div>");
   mapDiv.insertAfter($(this));
});
```

The issue is that some links have brackets/braces after them and this creates an ugly split for the new div. Is there a good method to see if there's a space or end of paragraph following the link and, if not, move however many characters until a space is reached?

Comment: You should post more of your code because it is hard to tell what you are doing, for example, how do you get `$(this)`, where is it coming from?

Comment: Apologies, I typically use $(this) as a reference to the anchor clicked and thought it was obvious and would keep the question concise. I can see the confusion now, I've edited the question to include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(this).parent().appendChild(mapDiv);
```

Assuming you want the new element to appear at the end of the element containing the link, which is what your example shows, this should work

Update:

```
<p>this is an example sentence with a link coming up (Here's the <span><a href='#' class='insertpoint'>link content</a>)</span>. More text may or may not follow here.</p>
```

To make my previous solution work you can simply wrap the link in a span so that the end of the parent of the anchor is where you would like to insert the new element

Or, if you want to deal with looking at the html, here is a start to a solution that will find the character proceeding the anchor tag, but this solution requires that all of your anchors have a unique id and that the id is the last attribute, i.e. it should appear right before the closing tag:

HTML:

```
<p>this is an example sentence with a link coming up (Here's the <a href='#' class='insertpoint' id="1">link content</a>). More text may or may not follow here.</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a.insertpoint").click(function() {  
    var mapDiv = $("<div class='map' id='testmap'><img src='http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'></div>");
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    var indexOfAnchorId = $(parent).html().indexOf($(this).attr("id"));
    var indexOfAnchorEnd = indexOfAnchorId + $(this).html().length + 7;
    alert($(parent).html()[indexOfAnchorEnd]);
   //mapDiv.insertAfter($(this));
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y09cvu6q/

Comment: Thanks Joe. If there was a guarantee of the anchor being in the last sentence of a paragraph, this would be great, but there's not. I've edited the example text so this assumption is clear. I think the solution is still along the lines of needing to determine what spacing follows the anchor.

Comment: It's a little less automated than I'd like but you gave me an idea of just inserting the content after a parent of the link, with a span like you mentioned. The second idea is good but it's not getting perfect placement each time. I think because some of my insertion placement is a little but subjective for aesthetic reasons, I may cave and go with the manually placed span idea for now. Thanks Joe.

Comment: To get the placement right for the second one, you have to make sure that the anchor is closed like `id="1">` exactly, not `id="1" >` or anything like that, any extra characters after the `id` will mess up the index. You could also try to find the position of the first `>` after the position of the `id` which would tell you right where the content of the anchor begins every time.  My example was a little crude because it just adds 7 to the index of the id, which would account for all of these characters: "></a> which appear after the id and are not included in the anchors content

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `.split()`

```
var str = "...a link coming up (here's the link content)."
var words = str.split(" ");
var lastWord = words[words.length - 1];
```

That should put you in about the right area to start doing whatever you want.

You might be able to do something like:

```
var link = '<a href="somewhere.com">' + lastWord + '</a>';
var newStr = str.replace(lastWord, link);
```

this is untested, but it's the start of a solution